# Get date of the day following week in php

Tags: java, php, android

I'm creating a appointment application in android and php patient can select appointments from the given list in android. The selected day will be send to server, and there appointments will shown in android fetched from server, time and date, time part is done,
date part
can't figure out how to get the date
problem is current day is Tuesday(5-12-2017) and someone make an appointment for Friday(8-12-2017), how to get date of Friday
And what if he makes and appointment for Monday(11-12-2017)
cant figure out how to do this, I can get current day and date but how to increment to the user defined day to get the date in PHP

Comment: have you tried  `date()` and `strtotime()`,   now that I think about it .. what have you tried.

Comment: Check this library, it is an adaptation of joda time for android. It makes dealing with time much easier. https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: the problem is to get the the date of the following day defined by user i have only current day, and what if the your defines monday and today is tuesday

Comment: use `+1 Days` in `DateTime->modify()`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yeah i can do that if i only knew what user will be selecting :( +1 for wed +2 for thurs

Comment: You make no sense you can do `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($userDate));`

Comment: With date time you and do `DateTime->modify('Friday this week')`   http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php  That said your question is FooBar and say they pick `Monday` and today is `Tuesday` then when you get `Monday this week` check if it's in the past, and then get monday from next week.  Gesh.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix user is not giving me the date, he is giving me a day, I've to increment to that day
like today is sunday(3-12-2017) to user defined {tuesday(5-12-2017)}
note that user is only sending a day, not the date. I've to get the date of following tuesday

Comment: Wait let me check and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
$choice = "Tuesday";

$Date = new DateTime();
$Clone = clone $Date;

$Clone->modify($choice." this week");

if( $Date > $Clone ){
    $Clone = clone $Date;
    $Clone->modify($choice." next week");
}

print_r($Clone->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Outputs

```
2017-12-05
```

You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1565820c302e767e4ec3231de9869b3eeb2a7e1)

Comment: You saved me, yes i can do that, and thats the selected ans :)

Comment: PS I hate dates.

Comment: :D same here buddy